# Constructors for public widgets should have a named 'key' parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating some classes but I am getting this error message:

**Constructors for public widgets should have a named 'key' parameter.**

I have tried to add the key but it is not working.

```
  const TitleCompanyScreen([this.isNewTitleCompany, this.titleCompanyId], {super.key});
```

How do I add the named 'key' parameter to a class?

**UPDATE:**

I made changes but I am still getting errors.

```
class TitleCompanyScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final bool? isNewTitleCompany;
  final String? titleCompanyId;

  const TitleCompanyScreen({[this.isNewTitleCompany, this.titleCompanyId]});
    
  @override
  ConsumerState<TitleCompanyScreen> createState() => _TitleCompanyScreenState();
}
```

If I don't initialize the final variables I get this error:

```
All final variables must be initialized, but 'isNewTitleCompany' and 'titleCompanyId' aren't.
Try adding initializers for the fields.
```

If I initialize the variables to false and '' respectively I get this error. the error is marked on the first [ in the line below:

```
const TitleCompanyScreen({[this.isNewTitleCompany, this.titleCompanyId]});
    Expected an identifier.dart(missing_identifier)
    Expected to find '}'.
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Presuming you're extending something like Widget, the key is indeed defined in some superclass.

Comment: When I add the super.key like I did I get another error saying I need a ) after the titleCompanyId]

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a lint, suggesting that super.key should be first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, a class constructor cannot simultaneously accept positional parameters
(such as `[this.isNewTitleCompany, this.titleCompanyId]`) and named parameters
(such as `{super.key}`) without defining them as either required or optional in
named form. This is due to the syntactic constraints of the Dart language,
designed to ensure clarity and prevent confusion when calling constructors
with multiple parameters.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TitleCompanyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isNewTitleCompany;
  final String? titleCompanyId;

  const TitleCompanyScreen([
    this.isNewTitleCompany,
    this.titleCompanyId,
    Key? key,
  ]) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use {} to surround the named parameters.
TitleCompanyScreen({this.isNewTitleCompany, this.titleCompanyId})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).